# Models generated by JOOQ require manual imports for third party libraries when using custom bindings

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I'm implementing a custom binding for JSONB support in JOOQ for my Postgresql db, as mentioned here: http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.8/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/

On running the code generator, the appropriate models are created, but gradle is giving me a build error as the models now need the `JsonElement` imported. Do I need to do something specific to make sure that the models that are generated have the appropriate libraries imported?

Thanks!

EDIT: I also have a Postgresql function that returns a JSONB, which get's it's corresponding Java class after code generation. But that's giving me a compile error as well. Here's a screenshot: [Compile error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRsga.png)

EDIT 2: My entire gradle build config:

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "application"

mainClassName = "com.vault.server.VaultServer"

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

defaultTasks = ['clean', 'build']

sourceSets {
    main {
        java { srcDir 'src' }
        resources { srcDir 'resources' }
    }
    test {
        java { srcDir 'test' }
        resources { srcDir 'resources' }
    }
    integTest {
        java.srcDir file('integrationTest')
        resources.srcDir file('resources')
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
        runtimeClasspath = output + compileClasspath
    }
}

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile "log4j:log4j:1.2.17"
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2"
    compile "org.jooq:jooq:3.8.4"
    compile "org.jooq:jooq-meta:3.8.4"
    compile "org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.8.4"
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:17.0"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.4"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.1.1"
    compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"
    compile "org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411"
    compile "org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.13"
    compile "redis.clients:jedis:2.6.0"
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1208.jre7'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:2.0.1'
    compile group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'jsr311-api', version: '1.1.1'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-bundle', version: '1.19'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-server', version: '1.19'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-core', version: '1.19'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-servlet', version: '1.19'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-json', version: '1.19'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-client', version: '1.19'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-grizzly2', version: '1.19'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
    testCompile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet', version: '2.21'
    testCompile group: 'com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework', name: 'jersey-test-framework-core', version: '1.19'
    testCompile group: 'com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework', name: 'jersey-test-framework-external', version: '1.19'
    testCompile group: 'com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework', name: 'jersey-test-framework-http', version: '1.19'
    testCompile group: 'com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework', name: 'jersey-test-framework-grizzly2', version: '1.19'
    testCompile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers', name: 'jersey-test-framework-provider-jetty', version: '2.6'
    testCompile group: 'com.sun.jersey.test.framework', name: 'jersey-test-framework', version: '1.0.3.1'
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3"
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.11"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.8.4"
    testCompile "org.easymock:easymock:3.4"
    testCompile "cglib:cglib:3.2.4"
    testCompile "org.objenesis:objenesis:2.4"
}

configurations {
  integTestCompile { extendsFrom testCompile, compile }
  integTestRuntime { extendsFrom integTestCompile, testRuntime }
}

jar {
    // adds runtime dependencies to jar package
    from(configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {
        // remove all signature files
        exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    }
    baseName = 'vault'
    manifest.attributes("Main-Class": mainClassName);
}

test {
  exclude 'com/vault/**'

  maxHeapSize '1024m'
  minHeapSize '512m'

}

task integTest(type: Test) {
  testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.integTest.output.classesDir
  classpath = project.sourceSets.integTest.runtimeClasspath
  exclude 'com/vault/**'

  maxHeapSize '1024m'
  minHeapSize '512m'
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
  testLogging { events 'passed' }

  if (System.getProperty('DEBUG', 'false') == 'true') {
    jvmArgs '-Xdebug',
      '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=4000'
  }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.0'
}

task generateVersion() {
    def git_hash = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec{
        executable "git"
        args "rev-parse", "--verify", "HEAD"
        standardOutput = git_hash
    }
    def version = git_hash.toString()
    new File("./resources/version").write(version)
    println "Git version is: " + version
}

build.dependsOn generateVersion

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'nu.studer:gradle-jooq-plugin:1.0.5'
        classpath 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1208.jre7' // database-specific JDBC driver
        classpath 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'nu.studer.jooq'

jooq {
    recordsDb(sourceSets.main) {
        jdbc {
            driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
            url = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/'
            user = 'postgres'
            password = 'xyz'
        }
        generator {
            name = 'org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator'
            strategy {
                name = 'org.jooq.util.DefaultGeneratorStrategy'
            }
            database {
                name = 'org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase'
                schemata {
                    schema {
                        inputSchema = "shard_0"
                    }
                }
            }
            customTypes {
                customType {
                    name = "JsonElement"
                    converter = "com.vault.dao.PostgresJSONGsonBinding"
                }
            }
            forcedTypes {
                forcedType {
                    name = "JsonElement"
                    expression = ".*data.*|.*tags.*"
                    types = ".*"
                }
            }
            generate {
                relations = true
                deprecated = false
                records = true
                immutablePojos = true
                fluentSetters = true
            }
            target {
                packageName = 'com.vault.jooq'
                directory = 'target/generated-sources'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PostgresJSONGsonBinding file:

```
package com.vault.dao;


import static org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggerFactory;
import org.jooq.*;
import org.jooq.impl.DSL;
import com.google.gson.*;

// We're binding <T> = Object (unknown JDBC type), and <U> = JsonElement (user type)
public class PostgresJSONGsonBinding implements Binding<Object, JsonElement> {

  // The converter does all the work
  @Override
  public Converter<Object, JsonElement> converter() {
    return new Converter<Object, JsonElement>() {
      @Override
      public JsonElement from(Object t) {
        return t == null ? JsonNull.INSTANCE : new Gson().fromJson("" + t, JsonElement.class);
      }

      @Override
      public Object to(JsonElement u) {
        return u == null || u == JsonNull.INSTANCE ? null : new Gson().toJson(u);
      }

      @Override
      public Class<Object> fromType() {
        return Object.class;
      }

      @Override
      public Class<JsonElement> toType() {
        return JsonElement.class;
      }
    };
  }

  // Rending a bind variable for the binding context's value and casting it to the json type
  @Override
  public void sql(BindingSQLContext<JsonElement> ctx) throws SQLException {
    ctx.render().visit(DSL.val(ctx.convert(converter()).value())).sql("::json");
  }

  // Registering VARCHAR types for JDBC CallableStatement OUT parameters
  @Override
  public void register(BindingRegisterContext<JsonElement> ctx) throws SQLException {
    ctx.statement().registerOutParameter(ctx.index(), Types.VARCHAR);
  }

  // Converting the JsonElement to a String value and setting that on a JDBC PreparedStatement
  @Override
  public void set(BindingSetStatementContext<JsonElement> ctx) throws SQLException {
    ctx.statement().setString(ctx.index(), Objects.toString(ctx.convert(converter()).value(), null));
  }

  // Getting a String value from a JDBC ResultSet and converting that to a JsonElement
  @Override
  public void get(BindingGetResultSetContext<JsonElement> ctx) throws SQLException {
    ctx.convert(converter()).value(ctx.resultSet().getString(ctx.index()));
  }

  // Getting a String value from a JDBC CallableStatement and converting that to a JsonElement
  @Override
  public void get(BindingGetStatementContext<JsonElement> ctx) throws SQLException {
    ctx.convert(converter()).value(ctx.statement().getString(ctx.index()));
  }

  // Setting a value on a JDBC SQLOutput (useful for Oracle OBJECT types)
  @Override
  public void set(BindingSetSQLOutputContext<JsonElement> ctx) throws SQLException {
    throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
  }

  // Getting a value from a JDBC SQLInput (useful for Oracle OBJECT types)
  @Override
  public void get(BindingGetSQLInputContext<JsonElement> ctx) throws SQLException {
    throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Configuration of user-defined types

The reason why you find missing imports is here:

```
customTypes {
    customType {
        // Lacking a "type" definition, jOOQ uses the "name" as the "type":
        name = "JsonElement"
        converter = "com.vault.dao.PostgresJSONGsonBinding"
    }
}
forcedTypes {
    forcedType {
        name = "JsonElement"
        expression = ".*data.*|.*tags.*"
        types = ".*"
    }
}
```

Since you only specified the `customType.name` property (and not also the `customType.type` property), jOOQ's code generator uses that `name` as the type information. But jOOQ doesn't know what that type means or where it is. I.e. you have three options to fix this:

**1. Add the type**

```
    customType {
        type = "com.google.gson.JsonElement"
        name = "JsonElement"
        converter = "com.vault.dao.PostgresJSONGsonBinding"
    }
```

**2. Replace the name by the qualified type**

```
customTypes {
    customType {
        name = "com.google.gson.JsonElement"
        converter = "com.vault.dao.PostgresJSONGsonBinding"
    }
}
forcedTypes {
    forcedType {
        name = "com.google.gson.JsonElement"
        expression = ".*data.*|.*tags.*"
        types = ".*"
    }
}
```

**3. Use jOOQ 3.8's simplified forced type configuration**

As documented in [the jOOQ 3.8+ manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types/), you can omit using `customType` configurations and use `forcedType` only:

```
    forcedType {
        userType = "com.google.gson.JsonElement"
        expression = ".*data.*|.*tags.*"
        types = ".*"
    }
```

Any of the above will solve the import problem.

#### Side note on jOOQ versions

Your screenshot suggests you're using jOOQ version 3.4.1. Please upgrade to the latest version (currently 3.8.4). There had been many bugfixes in this area.

It appears that version 3.4.1 is being pulled by your `nu.studer:gradle-jooq-plugin:1.0.5` version. See:

https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/blob/1.0.5/gradle.properties

You could upgrade to `1.0.6`, which pulls 3.6.2, which would be a bit better, but still not the latest version.

I suspect that's a bug / limitation to be fixed in that third party Gradle plugin. I have registered an issue for this:
https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/issues/18

Comment: Not sure why that's happening, I have these lines in my build.gradle file:
    compile "org.jooq:jooq:3.8.4"
    compile "org.jooq:jooq-meta:3.8.4"
    compile "org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.8.4"

Comment: @iman453 Can you post your entire code generation config to the question?

Comment: I added it a an edit to the question. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @iman453: OK, it looks like that particular jOOQ version is being pulled by the third party `gradle-jooq-plugin` that you were using. I have adapted my answer

Comment: Ah gotcha, yeah I changed it to 1.0.6 but that didn't fix it either. On average how long do you feel a bug like this would take to fix? (I'm sure you guys have a bunch of stuff on your plate, I don't mean to sound demanding :)) Is there any other workaround I could use while this bug is being fixed? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @iman453: I cannot say anything about when third party "bugs" can be fixed. Btw, where's your data type binding configuration? Perhaps there's simply something wrong in there...

Comment: ah sorry I missed that, I've added that now along with the actual converter code (which I just took from the official JOOQ site).

Comment: btw, the compile error I was getting in MergeTags which I posted a screenshot off isn't happening after getting on the latest version of the third party library :) Now just the JsonElement types not being imported issue remains

Comment: @iman453: I see, thanks for the update. With the update, the mistake is now clear. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ahh, I feel stupid, thanks for that. The type parameter is missing in the third party plugin's documentation: http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.3.0.xsd and so I didn't include it. I'll file a bug for them. Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: Well, it was added in jOOQ 3.4.0: http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.4.0.xsd. The latest version of the file is http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.8.0.xsd

Comment: Ah makes sense, the readme on the github of the third party plugin pointed to this so I assumed that was the latest. I had another question (sorry :S), I also have functions in postgresql that take in parameters of type json, but when I see the corresponding models generated by jooq, the input parameters are of type Object and when I run a simple select query with one of the select parameters being a call to that function I get an error: ERROR: function public.merge_fields_json(old_json => character varying, new_json => character varying) does not exist

Comment: I'm guessing the custom binding and forced types I've used only apply to tables and not to functions?

Comment: @iman453: Would you mind asking a new question here on Stack Overflow? It will be easier to answer than here in the comments :)

Comment: Sure, I added a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807777/how-to-call-a-postgresql-function-from-the-jooq-models-in-a-select-statement

Thanks again for your help, and hopefully I don't bug you any more after this question :)

Comment: Sorry to bug you @Lukas, but any chance you have an idea about what could be going wrong in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807777/how-to-call-a-postgresql-function-from-the-jooq-models-in-a-select-statement ? Or if there's some other place I could ask for help, I'd really appreciate that as well. Thanks!

Comment: @iman453: I'm sorry about that, that question slipped by my radar. Will look into it immediately